# Add a column to a CSV using Python

Tags: python, csv, field

I have a CSV file, which looks like this:

```
id,text,initial_score
1,"Today's news: Democrats offer Republicans everything they asked for; Republicans demand more. Not hard to understand: R's want a shutdown.",0
```

I want to create a new file, which include the same fields and add a new field as a column. The new field will be a result of an equalization.I used the following code but there is a syntax error:

```
f1 = open(filepathIntro)
f = open(filepath)
for line in f1:

    cols = split_line(line)
    words1 = get_tweet_words(cols)
    total_score = 0
    for w1 in words1:
        for line in f:
            if not line.startswith("#"):
                cols = split_line(line)
                words2 = get_words(cols)
                for w2 in words2:
                    if w1 == w2:
                        posnum = float(get_positive(cols))
                        negnum = float(get_negative(cols))
                        total_score = total_score + (posnum - negnum)

    with open(filepathIntro, 'r') as f1, open('semevalSenti.csv', 'w+' ) as fout:
        reader = csv.reader(f1)
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        writer.writerow(next(reader) + ['Total score'])
        writer.writerows([reader] + float(total_score) )
```

The message error is:

```
writer.writerows([a] + total_score for a,total_score  in zip(reader,total_score)) TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: Could you please provide the error message you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing paren at `writer.writerow(next(reader) + ['Total score'] <-`, also remove the set literal just `zip(reader, total_score)`

I presume `writer.writerow(line + total_score)` should be `writer.writerow(line + [val])` which means you can simplify the process by using `writerows` using the result of zipping once `total_score` is defined and an iterable the same length as the number of rows in the file originally:

```
with open(filepathIntro, newline='') as f1, open('semevalSenti.csv',newline='', 'w') as fout:
        reader = csv.reader(f1)
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        writer.writerow(next(reader) + ['Total score'])
        writer.writerows(a + [b] for a,b  in zip(reader, total_score)
```

Comment: now shows me this error: reader = csv.reader(f1, newline='', lineterminator='\n')
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @NellyBrili, I removed all the keywords, `newline=""` would  be used with open not csv.writer, the code as is should work fine

Comment: It's almost done! but now throws me the following error: writer.writerows([a] + b for a,b  in zip(reader, total_score))
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Comment: total score is the result of an equalization. Each line have words, each word have a sentiment, so total score is the sum of that sentiment. total_score=total_score+(pos_sentiment - neg_sentiment)

Comment: So a calculation based on existing values from each row? If so you will need to replace the [b] in the code with [your_calculation]

Comment: OK,  easiest thing might be to add a snippet of the file and your logic for the calculation and I can edit my answer to incorporate it. If total score is a calculation you would need to forget zipping and just use the reader object in the loop, create the b value based on your calculation

Comment: It shows the same error :( OK i add a snippet above

Comment: It errors because zip needs a list or some other iterable,  you need to forget zip, total_score  and add in the calculation for (pos_sentiment - neg_sentiment).

Comment: hm.... yes but i think that i need total score. Because i compare 2 files and if i find the word i increase or or not the total_score of each row. Could you please have a look at the snippet bellow? I really appreciate your help!!! :)

Comment: No prob, if you edit the code into your question it will be better, looking at your code initially there are quite a few issues, I will throw something together in a minute. Just one question, why are you keeping a running total?

Comment: ok. Done! i didnt know that. I keep it because i want to train a naive bayesian classifier due to this issue

Comment: Ok, this code should be closer to what you want http://pastebin.com/YyXMwrnQ without knowing how your data is structured and what exactly you are trying to do it is impossible to do much more but almost certainly your code could be a lot more efficient, as it stands it is quadratic and for large input would take a while to complete. Just so you know, when you iterate over  file object once it is exhausted so in your own code after the first `for line in f:` you never did another pass over it

Comment: I think that this is exactly what i need!!!!! Thank you very very very much for your help and for your time!!!!

Comment: No problem, like I said there are no doubt ways to greatly reduce the complexity but without seeing data and expected output it is hard to say exactly how but hopefully this will get you started at least :)

Comment: Hi, i have another problem. One of these 3 columns includes commas that break the CSV format. Do you know how can i fix that using python?

Comment: @NellyBrili, add a link to the data if possible

Comment: hi, i want to ask you sthn else, about python and encoding. Could you please help me?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: this is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998597/mongodb-input-and-output